# Git branching practice with two release targets

Tags: git, github

I have a simple question about git branching practice :

Say there are `master` & `develop` branches. All feature development tasks are working on corresponding feature branches, targeting at `develop` branch. (feature branch is branched off from `develop`)

I have tasks for the release of app version 1.0.0 , in the meantime, I have also tasks for the future release of app version 1.1.0.

I know in general, tasks should targeting at `develop` branch, but I don't want to release 1.0.0 which contains feature for 1.1.0 , so, I can't have all tasks merging to `develop` branch.

The solution I could come up with is having a `temporary` branch (branch off from `develop`) for 1.1.0, tasks for 1.1.0 merged to that `temporary` branch. Wait until release candidate branch for 1.0.0 is created, then, merge that `temporary` branch to `develop` for future release 1.1.0.

Do you have a better practice then what I come up with?

Comment: Why do you associate branches with "targets"? Branches can eventually be merged anywhere you need. Develop on your feature branch. If you later feel like merging it on 1.1.0 or 1.0.0, who cares?

Comment: replaced bold words by backtick words

Answer (score 1):

> I know in general, tasks should targeting at develop branch,

That is mainly true for the popular `git-flow` workflow. There is no "should" about it, and `git` itself has no opinion about how you use it.

`git-flow` works when you have just a single "next" release, if you pretty well know what goes into the next release, and if you usually do not wish to back out changes from your `develop` branch. For example, in my current main project, these three assumptions are *wrong*. So we do not use `git-flow`.

> The solution I could come up with is having a temporary branch (branch off from develop)

Why branch off of `develop`, in the first place? You can use `master` (with the meaning of "current release") instead. If all your branches are sourced from `master`, and you get rid of `develop`, and you have ephemeral future-release-branches which are frequently re-built from scratch (reset to master, merge all relevant features into them) there is no problem targetting multiple future releases while still developing all new features in parallel. There is a workflow called [branch-per-feature](http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/) which is very great for this.

Comment: Yep, I know there is no "should" in git, I can do whatever I want, but I just use "should" to describe the popular convention-like workflow.  Branching off from `develop` because development work are supposed to merge to the `develop` version code. I created the `temporary` branch from `develop` because the future release (the release after next release) are under development as well.  Probably you are talking about this:  https://barro.github.io/2016/02/a-succesful-git-branching-model-considered-harmful/

Comment: @Leem, that's what I meant, with trying to keep my opinion out of it - I feel `git-flow` is a bit overhyped; and am sometimes a bit unhappy that especially newer developers or team always seem to auto-target that workflow. I have nothing in particular against it, if it fits the job, but I have seen plenty of projects which would have been better off with another approach. Exploring other workflows, i.e. the one I linked, may give you a few ideas, which you maybe can integrate into your particular situation.

Comment: Thanks, I am sure the `git-flow` is not the best, that's also the reason I post a question here :)  Thanks for your opinion, I will read your recommended link & re-think the best option for my project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question will vary by workflow (and that will vary by team preferences and project nature), so the question flirts with being opinion-based or over-broad... but I guess some general thoughts would be:

The easiest thing is to minimize the overlapping time during which features are being developed for multiple releases.  From a priority-and-effort standpoint, this usually makes sense anyway.

For example the popular gitflow workflow more or less assumes that open `feature` branches are all (at least potentially) for the upcoming release.  Once you close the feature set for version `x`, you create the version `x` release branch.  Only release-related work and minor bugfixes should occur on the release branch (which eventually gets merged back to `develop` so that such fixes aren't lost).  And it's when the feature `x` release branch is created, that any open features become "version `x+1` features" and you open any new features that you already were withholding for the `x+1` release.

(A related point: it is often useful to be flexible in what features go to what release, so that you can release when the time comes with whatever value is ready to go.  This is somewhat related to agile thinking.)

But if you find that actively developing two versions is the way to go for your project, you'll need to do something different.  I'd get away from the idea of a `develop` branch at all, because of the branch name juggling that would ensue.

So then release-development branches (e.g. `dev-1.0.0`) could replace `develop`.  You'd create a release-development branch from the prior release-development branch, but thereafter you'd have to regularly incorporate changes from the previous release-development branch into the current release-development branch.  Since this is a shared/long-lived branch, you wouldn't want to do that by `rebase`, which means periodic merge commits are likely what you'd need.

There are other ways, and like I said it wanders quickly into opinion territory once you get away from the documented-and-time-tested approaches.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That's also a way I had in my mind, I will think about the best option which fits my project from the answers I received here :)